# Code to copy a character to another location in same file

Tags: java, groovy

Hi I have an input file and i need to get the output. I am trying java code and Groovy code as well,but unable to find the result.  Let me know if some one can help. The input is a txt file and all the values are in one column only.

Input :

```
A B C D E
  F G H I
  J K L M 
N O P Q R
  S T U V
  W X Y Z
```

Output :

```
A B C D E
A F G H I
A J K L M 
N O P Q R
N S T U V
N W X Y Z
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
data['R1']= R.toString()
for (int i=0; i<R.length(); i++) { 
    if (i==1) R['i']= 'A';
    if (i==2) R[i] = 'A';
    if (i==4) R[i] ='S';
    if (i ==5) R['i'] = 'S'; 
 }
println R
```

Comment: data['R1']= R.toString()
for (int i=0; i<R.length(); i++) 
{
if (i==1)
R['i']= 'A';
if (i==2)
R[i] = 'A';
if (i==4)
R[i] ='S';
if (i ==5)
R['i'] = 'S';
}
println R;

Comment: I have tried Java code as well. but it is not working..

Comment: The logic is to just copy the above cell and print it in empty space, but i am not able to.

Comment: please edit the question, when you have code etc.  also "does not work" is a poor error description.

Comment: So what language is your code? Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Java or Groovy, both works on my software platform

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in Groovy

```
// Mock the input file
def input = """A B C D E
  F G H I
  J K L M 
N O P Q R
  S T U V
  W X Y Z"""

def inputFile = new StringReader(input)

// Process the input file
inputFile
    .iterator()
    .collect { it.split(" ") } // Break each line into columns.
    .inject([keep : null, rows : []]) { context, row ->
        if(row[0]) {
            /*
             * If the row contains a value in the first column,
             * remember the value and keep the row as-is.
             */
            [
                keep : row[0], 
                rows : context.rows + row
            ]
        } else {
            /*
             * If the row doesn't have a value in the first column,
             * prepend the remembered value to the row.
             */
            [
                keep : context.keep, 
                rows : context.rows << [context.keep] + row.drop(2).flatten()
            ]
        }
    }
    .rows // The context is no longer needed, so just grab the rows form it.
```

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, I tried doing it but it is not doing anything when I try to run it. No output is being generated. Can you kindly let me know that while defining the input " " " A B C D E and the rows below it I have used | and .StripMargin() so that if it does not read " " " multiline inout it will read by this method. But still it is not processing anything.

Comment: Also the inputFile.iterator() has to written like this or like you have shown to me in example. and do I need to include inputFile before .collect and .inject lines. As it is not parsing the code.